# How to ensure Twilio returns the correct event callback?

Tags: twilio

My calls are connecting fine to the client app, and I can chat over it. However, the status of the call sent during callback events seems to be wrong.

Below is my TwiML.

```
response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new do |r|
  r.dial do |d|
    d.client(identity: 'xx@gmail.com',
             status_callback_event: 'initiated ringing answered completed',
             status_callback: 'https://example.com/twilio_callbacks/call_status',
             status_callback_method: 'POST')
    
  end
end
```

After the call is completed, I receive a callback with parameter `CallStatus` of `no-answer`, but checking the logs on Twilio, I was connected, and the call should have a status of `completed` instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [completed statusCallback event may have many different statuses, from "no-answer", "busy", "completed", "failed" or "cancelled"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#parameters-sent-to-your-statuscallback-url).

If, however, you believe the call status is wrong, then you should get the call SID and contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can look into what happened with the call.